# Display date time with hours and minutes

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to display date time as follows `Wednesday, 05 May 2014 21:25`

I tried the following but when using `ToLongDateString` I am not getting time, this is my code

```
 DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
 string formattedDate = date.ToLongDateString();
 string fDate = date.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy,H:mm");
 Response.Write(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Date string does not include time. That's why it called *date* string. Here is your desired format:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
string formattedDate = date.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm");
// Wednesday, 07 May 2014 12:05
```

Answer (score 3):

`ToLongDateString` does not contain the time, as the time is not part of the date.
See [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolongdatestring.aspx) for some details:

> Current culture: "en-US"
>
> Long date pattern: "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy" Long date string: 
>   "Wednesday, May 16, 2001"
>
> Long time pattern: "h:mm:ss tt" Long time string:  "3:02:15 AM"
>
> Short date pattern: "M/d/yyyy" Short date string:  "5/16/2001"
>
> Short time pattern: "h:mm tt" Short time string:  "3:02 AM"

Also [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on all the possiblities with `ToString` for `DateTime`.

**You possibly want to use `ToString("F")`**:

> The "F" standard format specifier represents a custom date and time
>   format string that is defined by the current
>   DateTimeFormatInfo.FullDateTimePattern property. For example, the
>   custom format string for the invariant culture is "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy
>   HH:mm:ss".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the string `dddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm`.

```
 string fDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm");
 Response.Write(fDate );
```

Also, your code is outputting `formattedDate` not the `fDate` value.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;               // Use current time
string format = "dddd, d MMM yyyy HH:mm";   // Use this format
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString(format));   // Write to console
```

for more details visit below page
http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format

Answer (score 0):

Your can try this

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
                string formattedDate = date.ToLongDateString();
                string fDate = date.ToString("dddd  MMMM dd, yyyy  hh:mm");
                Response.Write(fDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

This format should work:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
string formattedDate = date.ToString("f"); 
// January 13, 2023 5:00 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like the format that just doing ToString() gives me e.g

```
HelperLib.LogMsg("Job Ran at + " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
// Job Ran at 21/01/2023 21:12:59
```

You can change the format with hh:mm if you don't want seconds as people have shown you above, however this format is exactly what I want and need. If I wanted the day name or month name I would use the formatting people have shown you above but for mew this gives me the Date and time and any variable that is a date format it works on e.g

```
DateTime raceDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(RecordsetRow["RaceDateTime"]);

Console.WriteLine("racedatetime = " + raceDateTime.ToString();
```

and the same output...

Answer (score -1):

The following should work:

```
string formattedDate = date.ToLongDateString();
formattedDate += date.ToString(" h:mm");
```

Comment: Nope; they want 24-hour time.

Comment: oh, i missed that... replace " h:mm" with " H:mm"